# How to call function from a different local script?

Tags: roblox

I have a thing that heals the player if they get into the room. And I want to players who are in the room to see a green screen borders flash effect upon healing. How can I achieve this? I tried to use local script so that everyone won't have the flash effect but don't know how to activate it since healing script is a normal script while flash screen is a local script. Also, if there are any other ways of solving this problem rather than activating function from another script, I will be glad to hear it.

Here is some code if this will help:
Heal script

```
desc = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.Desc
status = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.Status
bar = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.BarBG.Bar
barBG = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.BarBG
hitBox = script.Parent.Parent.Hitbox

local charge = 0
local MaxCharge = 100
local playersInBox = {}

status.Text = "ACTIVE"
status.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(100, 255, 100)
desc.Text = "BIOREGENERATOR IS CURRENTLY ACTIVE AND OPERATIONAL. RESTORES HEALTH AND SANITY OF NEARBY HUMANS IN THIS ROOM."
desc.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 150, 0)

hitBox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name ~= "HumanoidRootPart" then return end
    if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not player then return end
    if not table.find(playersInBox, player) then
        table.insert(playersInBox, player)
    else
        return
    end
end)

hitBox.TouchEnded:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name ~= "HumanoidRootPart" then return end
    if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not player then return end
    if table.find(playersInBox, player) then
        local num = table.find(playersInBox, player)
        table.remove(playersInBox, num)
    else
        return
    end
end)

while true do
    if charge ~= 100 then
        repeat
            charge = charge + 0.5
            bar.Size = UDim2.new(charge / MaxCharge, 0, 1, 0)
            wait()
        until charge == MaxCharge
    else
        for index, value in ipairs(playersInBox) do
            if not value.Character then table.remove(value) continue end
            local char = value.Character
            local human = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
            local MaxSP = human:FindFirstChild("MaxSP")
            local SP = human:FindFirstChild("SP")
            human.Health += 12
            SP.Value += 12
            if SP.Value > MaxSP.Value then
                SP.Value = MaxSP.Value
            end
        end
        charge = 0
    end
    wait()
end
```

Flash script:

```
function flash()
    local healFlash = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.HealFlash
    healFlash.ImageTransparency = 0
    repeat
        healFlash.ImageTransparency += 0.05
        wait()
    until healFlash.ImageTransparency == 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is actually quite simple, turn the Flash script into a `ModuleScript` and then require it in main script.

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ModuleScript

FlashScript (Child of Main script):

```lua
local module = {}

function module.flash()
    local healFlash = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.HealFlash
    healFlash.ImageTransparency = 0
    repeat
        healFlash.ImageTransparency += 0.05
        wait()
    until healFlash.ImageTransparency == 1
end

return module
```

^ In this code snippet we need to add the function to a table and then return that table so it can be accessed when required. If there isn't a return statement it will fail.

Main Script:

```lua
local flashScript = require(script.FlashScript)
flashScript.flash()

desc = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.Desc
status = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.Status
bar = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.BarBG.Bar
barBG = script.Parent.SurfaceGui.BlackBG.BarBG
hitBox = script.Parent.Parent.Hitbox

local charge = 0
local MaxCharge = 100
local playersInBox = {}

status.Text = "ACTIVE"
status.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(100, 255, 100)
desc.Text = "BIOREGENERATOR IS CURRENTLY ACTIVE AND OPERATIONAL. RESTORES HEALTH AND SANITY OF NEARBY HUMANS IN THIS ROOM."
desc.TextColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 150, 0)

hitBox.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name ~= "HumanoidRootPart" then return end
    if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not player then return end
    if not table.find(playersInBox, player) then
        table.insert(playersInBox, player)
    else
        return
    end
end)

hitBox.TouchEnded:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name ~= "HumanoidRootPart" then return end
    if not hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then return end
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if not player then return end
    if table.find(playersInBox, player) then
        local num = table.find(playersInBox, player)
        table.remove(playersInBox, num)
    else
        return
    end
end)

while true do
    if charge ~= 100 then
        repeat
            charge = charge + 0.5
            bar.Size = UDim2.new(charge / MaxCharge, 0, 1, 0)
            wait()
        until charge == MaxCharge
    else
        for index, value in ipairs(playersInBox) do
            if not value.Character then table.remove(value) continue end
            local char = value.Character
            local human = char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
            local MaxSP = human:FindFirstChild("MaxSP")
            local SP = human:FindFirstChild("SP")
            human.Health += 12
            SP.Value += 12
            if SP.Value > MaxSP.Value then
                SP.Value = MaxSP.Value
            end
        end
        charge = 0
    end
    wait()
end
```

^ Line 1 loads the module script and then you can move line two to where ever you need it in the code. Line 2 calls the function. You can now use arguments and return values as if the function was in the main script.

If you need any more help, just reply :)

-- Harvey